# Real-time messaging between PHP backend and JAVA frontend

Tags: java, php, real-time, message-queue, messaging

My company has a desktop application which is made in JAVA and is communicating with PHP backend. Now, we have many clients, who are all given with a desktop app, and for each client there are many orders which are coming in. Currently, the desktop app is polling the PHP backend every 30 seconds to check if there is any new order or not, I want to optimize this process by either using a messaging protocol to relay the information as most of the polling requests go empty (900 out of 1000) or by improving polling mechanism.
I studied about MQTT and XMPP but was unable to understand. Also, I was thinking of using sockets but then someone said that there can be a problem with the port and all.
Is polling better or push, in this case?
If polling is better then how can I improve it since it is directly querying DB (which is wrong, it should go through a cache layer) or if push is better then how I can implement it?

Comment: `Pusher.com` is perfect for this..

Comment: @OleKristianAanensen: I have heard about Pusher, it was even my first choice but from what I have heard, Pusher uses GCM and APN to convey messages to Android/iOS devices and that GCM/APN are not reliable which it's concerned with important data. Though I don't know how it works with desktop apps.

Comment: Make sure you check the [Realtime Messaging platform](http://framework.realtime.co/messaging). Since it's a managed pub/sub broker your desktop application and the PHP backend can communicate (by publishing and subscribing data channels) in a loosely coupled way while using "normal" HTTP ports (80 or 443).

Comment: Isn't this same as Pusher?
I want to use a mechanism which can also be used for Android, iOS and Window Phone in near future.

Comment: @Vivek Realtime Messaging is a cloud pub/sub broker just like Pusher and it has several mobile SDKs, including native iOS, native Android, native Windows Phone, Cordova, PhoneGap, Unity and Titanium. All using websockets when app is active and push notifications when in background or closed.